# How to convert columns to rows using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I need to convert columns to rows and rows to columns. I have both column headers and rows headers to the left. The row headers are just bold text to the left of the row to define what the row is.

I am trying to make this table mobile friendly. The table is 7 columns wide and the 7 columns do not show in a smart phone. So my idea is to use a media query to display a table where the columns and rows are switched since there will be no more than 3 rows. Can this be done?

Comment: Could you jsfiddle your table ? How many rows it have?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6k7vd/1/)**

**Css Solution:** Simply turn your `td` & `th` to `display:block;` & your `tr` to `display:table-cell;`

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
    table tr > *{
        display: block;
    }
    table tr {
        display: table-cell;
    }
}
```

**Drawback:** If your cells have too much data the layout will break **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6k7vd/3/)**.

**jQuery Solution:** We can keep track of element height to stay the same **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6k7vd/18/)**

JS:

```
$(function () {
    switchRowsAndCols("table", 767);
});

function switchRowsAndCols(thisTable, resolution) {
    if ($(window).width() < resolution) {
        switchRowsAndColsInnerFun(thisTable);
    }
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < resolution) {
            switchRowsAndColsInnerFun(thisTable);
        }else{
            switchRowsAndColsRemove(thisTable);
        }
    });
};

function switchRowsAndColsRemove(thisTable) {
    $("tr > *", thisTable).css({
        height: 'auto'
    });
};

function switchRowsAndColsInnerFun(thisTable) {
    var maxRow = $("tr:first-child() > *", thisTable).length;

    for (var i = maxRow; i >= 0; i--) {

        $("tr > *:nth-child(" + i + ")", thisTable).css({
            height: 'auto'
        });

        var maxHeight = 0;

        $("tr > *:nth-child(" + i + ")", thisTable).each(function () {
            var h = $(this).height();
            maxHeight = h > maxHeight ? h : maxHeight;
        });

        $("tr > *:nth-child(" + i + ")", thisTable).each(function () {
            $(this).height(maxHeight);
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: @NicholasHazel That simple solution had an issue -- if you put too much data i.e line break the layout crumbled & i cant think of any css solution so here is some jQuery -- please see my updated answer.

Comment: @ImranBughio - Decided to toss out a super quick strict jQuery solution. If you're going to use jQuery at all, use it well :-) (your answer was perfectly reasonable as well).

Comment: Also add 

    table colgroup {
      display: none;
    }

Answer (score 2):

Well, figured I'd offer a slightly different `jQuery` solution to your dilemma for other people looking for additional help.

If you *have* to use a script, might as well make it do everything (the following script takes `4.2ms` to run, which seems pretty reasonable to me :-)

Essentially what the below is doing is taking your `tabular-data` and converting it to a `multidimensional array`.

```
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 8 
9, 10, 11, 12
```

**Becomes:**

```
[[1,5,9],[2,6,10],[3,7,11],[4,8,12]]
```

Then, it's just a matter of having it rewrite your `table` based on the new `array` with a couple `for-loops`.

**One thing to note, you would have to bind this to a `media query` or `window.resize` handler to get the acquired affect you're looking for. That is as easy as changing the `on.click` handler I have assigned.**

**Take a look! It's pretty nifty:**

#### http://jsfiddle.net/jsR7n/1/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" id="switch" value="switch" \>
<table id="switchItems">
<tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>...etc
```

**jQuery Script:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#switch').on('click', function(){
        var items = [];
        var itemsConv = [];
        var table = $('#switchItems');
        var row,cell;

// FIND ALL OF THE DATA
        $("tr").each(function(){
            var trRow = [];
            $(this).children().each(function() {
                trRow.push($(this).text());
            });
            items.push(trRow);
        });
        for(var j=0;j<items[0].length;j++){
            var newRow = [];
            for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
                newRow.push(items[i][j]);
            }
            itemsConv.push(newRow);
        }

// KILL OUR CURRENT DATA IN THE TABLE
        table.empty();

// REWRITE OUR TABLE WITH NEW DATA
        for(var i=0; i<itemsConv.length; i++){
            row = $( '<tr />' );
            table.append( row );
            for(var j=0; j<itemsConv[i].length; j++){
                cell = $('<td>'+itemsConv[i][j]+'</td>');
                row.append( cell );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Hope this was helpful!**

#### http://jsfiddle.net/jsR7n/1/

Comment: nice, i was just looking on internet there are lots of small script who do the same tasks but there isn't any proper registered jQuery plugin, may be we should upload a plugin our-self?

Comment: Sure, want to use git?

Comment: lets continue the discussion in [Chat Room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52349/discussion-between-nicholas-hazel-and-imran-bughio)

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way of doing it using html and css

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

table {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  table tr>* {
    display: block;
  }
  table tr {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Head 1</th>
    <th>Head 2</th>
    <th>Head 3</th>
    <th>Head 4</th>
    <th>Head 5</th>
    <th>Head 6</th>
    <th>Head 7</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 2</td>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 3</td>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 4</td>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 5</td>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 6</td>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/reishabh/b2d9wc3L/4/