# Columns and rows in css

Tags: css, html

I would like to convert a column to a row, and display it with the other rows on 1 line. I don't know if it is possible, but if it is, please help! I want to convert table column into table row only using CSS. The table is good, it works fine, but i want to make it responsive, everything on a vertical line, i just get this as result, a Γ shape.

this is what i got:

```
@media screen and (max-width:650px)

{

    table, thead, tbody, tr, th, td{

          display:block;
    }
    thead tr { 
          display:none;
    }
    tbody tr{
          display:table-row;
          width:auto;
    }
}
```

*/This is what i goit in HTML*/

```
<table width="1400px">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>a1</th>
                            <th>a2</th>
                            <th>a3</th>
                            <th>a4</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>b1</td>
                            <td rowspan="13">b2</td>
                            <td rowspan="13">b3</td>
                            <td rowspan="13">b4</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>c1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>d1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>e1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                           <td>f1</td> 
                        </tr>
                        <tr>  
                            <td>g1</td>  
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>h1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                           <td>i1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>j1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>k1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>l1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>m1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>n1</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you want to convert a table column into a table row using only CSS?

Comment: yes, i want to convert table column into table row only using CSS

Comment: the table is good, it works fine, but i want to make it responsive, everything  on a vertical line, and i get an F figure without the middel stripe of the F.

Comment: If you mean you get a Γ shape, I don't see it.

Comment: yeah i get that shape

Comment: using only wont work to change the table layout as you can't change the column positions or row, you need to use scripting to achieve that, but if you use flexbox it might solve your problem to change columns into rows when resizing, https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties or https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert columns to rows using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556364/how-to-convert-columns-to-rows-using-css)