# Transpose foundation block grid with css

Tags: css

Is there any way to transpose a [foundation block grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#block-grids) using CSS? Currently I have a list of category names ordered alphabetically that foundation block grid puts in 4 columns. For example, the category list items look like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
  <li>H</li>
  <li>I</li>
  <li>J</li>
  <li>K</li>
  <li>L</li>
  <li>M</li>
  <li>N</li>
</ul>
```

I use the following scss to create a block grid:

```
ul {
  @include grid-row;
  @include grid-layout(4, 'li');
}
```

The result is the categories broke into 4 columns, laid out in order horizontally:

```
A B C D
E F G H
I J K L
M N
```

However, I want this list to be transposed so that the the item are laid out in columns, like this:

```
A E I M
B F J N
C G K
D H L
```

I found the [jquery-transpose](https://github.com/litera/jquery-transpose) plugin that works great, but this category list is in a dropdown menu, that is initially hidden. The plugin needs to the list to be visible so it can determine how many rows and columns there are. This means I need to watch for when the menu become visible and call the plugin.

I can do that, but I was hoping to find a CSS solution instead. Is this possible?

Here's a codepen showing the markup. The codepen uses native foundation classes rather than css mixins, but it's the same effect:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLLXXo

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556364/how-to-convert-columns-to-rows-using-css/23586867

Comment: Did my answer help you at all?? Was a resolution found elsewhere? What did you end up with?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing a codepen. I wasn't sure of what you were asking, exactly, so I went ahead and made a couple examples for your review.

There's two in this codepen. Key Features for each below:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzLBeO

- Example 1

  - `writing-mode: vertical-lr;`
  - `float`
- Example 2

  - `transform: rotate();`
  - `float`

There's plenty more examples that I can come up with, but I think you'll get the idea.

You can take advantage of the `display:[table-element]` styles, column styles, heck, you could abuse some css selectors and throw in a variety of styles.

This is a generic question; you'll have to give me more for a more specific example/answer.

Comment: Thank you, I've been trying to use one of these methods to make it work, but am having trouble. Are you able to provide an answer that accomplishes this for an existings foundation block grid, as shown in my question? In other words, take my Codepen, and write some custom CSS rules to accomplish this, without removing the foundation classes. Your examples seem to work so I'm not sure why I'm having trouble implementing it for my use case.