# Make table responsive on mobile devices using HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive

I have this table that is part of a larger email. When the user's device is a mobile phone, or small screen I want the table to go from 2 columns/2 rows, to 1 column 4 rows. Would like to use the least amount of code possible.

```
<table style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;border-collapse:separate !important;border-spacing:20px 40px; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#333333; font-size:16px; line-height:24px; font-weight:100;" class="bodywrapcenter">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Dr. Andrew Borg<br>
      Chapter Advisor<br>
      aborg@example.edu<br>
    </td>
    <td>
      Stuart J. Sigman, PhD<br>
      Dean, College of Arts and Sciences<br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Dr. Dale Mancini<br>
      Chapter Advisor<br>
      dmancini@example.edu<br>
    </td>
    <td>
      David DeHaven, PhD<br>
      Dean, Graduate School of Business and Management<br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Use divs and bootstrap or other grid system.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556364/how-to-convert-columns-to-rows-using-css

Comment: @ArunKumar No, that question is about pivoting rows and columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using Bootstrap for responsive tables.

The `.table-responsive` class creates a responsive table. The table will then scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768 px). When viewing on anything larger than 768 px wide.

Use `.table-responsive{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}` as needed to create responsive tables up to a particular breakpoint. From that breakpoint and up, the table will behave normally and not scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 6):

```css
/*
    Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty. This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px and also iPads specifically.
    */

@media only screen and (max-width: 760px), (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
  table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
    display: block;
  }
  /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
  thead tr {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
  }
  tr {
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
  }
  tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #ccc;
  }
  td {
    /* Behave  like a "row" */
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50%;
  }
  td:before {
    /* Now like a table header */
    position: absolute;
    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
    top: 0;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  /*
        Label the data
    You could also use a data-* attribute and content for this. That way "bloats" the HTML, this way means you need to keep HTML and CSS in sync. Lea Verou has a clever way to handle with text-shadow.
        */
  td:nth-of-type(1):before {
    content: "First Name";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(2):before {
    content: "Last Name";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(3):before {
    content: "Job Title";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(4):before {
    content: "Favorite Color";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(5):before {
    content: "Wars of Trek?";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(6):before {
    content: "Secret Alias";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(7):before {
    content: "Date of Birth";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(8):before {
    content: "Dream Vacation City";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(9):before {
    content: "GPA";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(10):before {
    content: "Arbitrary Data";
  }
}
```

```html
<table role="table">
  <thead role="rowgroup">
    <tr role="row">
      <th role="columnheader">First Name</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Last Name</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Job Title</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Favorite Color</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Wars or Trek?</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Secret Alias</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Date of Birth</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Dream Vacation City</th>
      <th role="columnheader">GPA</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Arbitrary Data</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody role="rowgroup">
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="cell">James</td>
      <td role="cell">Matman</td>
      <td role="cell">Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
      <td role="cell">Lettuce Green</td>
      <td role="cell">Trek</td>
      <td role="cell">Digby Green</td>
      <td role="cell">January 13, 1979</td>
      <td role="cell">Gotham City</td>
      <td role="cell">3.1</td>
      <td role="cell">RBX-12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="cell">The</td>
      <td role="cell">Tick</td>
      <td role="cell">Crimefighter Sorta</td>
      <td role="cell">Blue</td>
      <td role="cell">Wars</td>
      <td role="cell">John Smith</td>
      <td role="cell">July 19, 1968</td>
      <td role="cell">Athens</td>
      <td role="cell">N/A</td>
      <td role="cell">Edlund, Ben (July 1996).</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="cell">Jokey</td>
      <td role="cell">Smurf</td>
      <td role="cell">Giving Exploding Presents</td>
      <td role="cell">Smurflow</td>
      <td role="cell">Smurf</td>
      <td role="cell">Smurflane Smurfmutt</td>
      <td role="cell">Smurfuary Smurfteenth, 1945</td>
      <td role="cell">New Smurf City</td>
      <td role="cell">4.Smurf</td>
      <td role="cell">One</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="cell">Cindy</td>
      <td role="cell">Beyler</td>
      <td role="cell">Sales Representative</td>
      <td role="cell">Red</td>
      <td role="cell">Wars</td>
      <td role="cell">Lori Quivey</td>
      <td role="cell">July 5, 1956</td>
      <td role="cell">Paris</td>
      <td role="cell">3.4</td>
      <td role="cell">3451</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="cell">Captain</td>
      <td role="cell">Cool</td>
      <td role="cell">Tree Crusher</td>
      <td role="cell">Blue</td>
      <td role="cell">Wars</td>
      <td role="cell">Steve 42nd</td>
      <td role="cell">December 13, 1982</td>
      <td role="cell">Las Vegas</td>
      <td role="cell">1.9</td>
      <td role="cell">Under the couch</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

View :https://codepen.io/Waruna/pen/pmEJvg

Comment: This works very well, except for one bugbear, which is the the CSS required for each individual column.

Answer (score 2):

Give below css to mobile breakpoint in your css code, and you're all done...

```
table.bodywrapcenter>tr>td {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping in a Div

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
<table>
...
</table>
</div>
```

From W3Schools - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_table_responsive.asp