# Transposed html table not aligned correctly

Tags: html, css, angular

I have html table implemented in angular application which is dynamically populated rows. I need to transpose so that columns render as rows.

I have managed to apply the css to transpose it but the alignment is not correct. could somebody suggest a solution to this problem

As you can see in the css below i have used to transpose

```
tr {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
th, td {
  display: block;
}
```

Original table

[image]

Transposed table

[image]

html

```
<style>

    th,
    td {
        padding: 7px;
    }

    .fundClassesTable {
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-size: 11px;
    }

    .tableItem {
        text-align: center;
        border-left: solid 1px lightgrey;
        border-top: solid 1px lightgrey;
        border-right: solid 1px lightgrey;
        border-bottom: solid 1px lightgrey;
        width: 100px
    }

    .rowItem:hover {
        background-color: #f5f7f7;
    }

/*
    tr {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
th, td {
  display: block;
}
    */




</style>


<div *ngIf="FundClasses && FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel">

    <table class="fundClassesTable" >

        <tr>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Accounting Class Name</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Class ID</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Legal Fund Class</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Inception Date</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Invested Amount</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Vehicle Type</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Closure Status</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Is Side Pocket?</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Is Thematic?</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Cogency Class?</th>
        </tr>

        <div *ngFor="let fundClass of FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel" >
            <tr *ngFor="let f of fundClass['FundClassDetailsViewModel'] | keyvalue">
                <td class="tableItem">{{ f.value.Description}}</td>
                <td class="tableItem">{{f.value.Id}}</td>
                <td class="tableItem">{{ f.value.LegalFundClassId}}</td>
                <td class="tableItem">{{f.value.InceptionDate}}</td>
                <td class="tableItem">{{ f.value.InvestedAmount}}</td>
                <td class="tableItem">{{f.value.ClosureStatusId}}</td>
                <td class="tableItem">{{ f.value.VehicleTypeId}}</td>
                <td class="tableItem">{{f.value.IsSidePocket}}</td>
                <td class="tableItem">{{ f.value.IsThematic}}</td>
                <td class="tableItem">{{f.value.CogencyClassId}}</td>
            </tr>
        </div>


    </table> 


</div>
```

Output based on Sashi's comment

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the CSS-only solution (assuming you've already replaced the `div` inside your table with `ng-container`), but it'll break when text inside the cells is too long.

```
table tr > * {
    display: block;
}
table tr {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

You can find a JS solution here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/23556911](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23556911/9540991)

Answer (score 0):

As we can see, the cell values that are empty before transposing, are getting misaligned after transposing. Please try to add a minimum height to the cells after transposed.

```
tr {
   display: block;
   float: left;
}

th, td {
  display: block;
  min-height: 20px; //change the value as per your need
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and posted the output in the post. Better but not perfectly aligned yet

Comment: Since there are no pre-defined width and height for the cells i.e.<td>, please assign the same. in our case, it should be width before transposing,                          td {  min-width: 200px; } and height as specified above after transposing. //change the values as per your need.